# How is Scala scalable?

Tags: scala, scalability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Scala more scalable than other languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130335/why-is-scala-more-scalable-than-other-languages)

The [Wikipedia page on Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) says:

> The name Scala is a portmanteau of "scalable" and "language", signifying that it is designed to grow with the demands of its users.

I've also [read that](http://work.tinou.com/2009/06/scalas-dirty-little-secret-to-scalability.html):

> And that's Scala's dirty little secret. Scala is only scalable in the sense that it runs on the reliable, high-performing JVM platform.

and also that "languages don't scale, platforms scale."

How does Scala grow with demands of its users? Isn't it true to say that Scala "actually is scalable"? And as per line just above, isn't every language scalable?

Comment: "Languages don't scale" - a lie. Meta-languages, such as Lisp, *do*  scale, without any limits. There are no metaprogramming capabilities in Scala at all, so yes, it won't scale.

Comment: I suppose languages can scale in the sense that their syntax makes it easy to code solutions to simple problems, while at the same time they have more powerful language constructs to tackle more difficult problems.

Comment: The top-voted answer talks about `flexibility and expressiveness`. Isn't Python expressive? Or any other languange? Aren't other languages like C++/Python flexible? Atleast Java is flexible enough that Scala was made on top of the JVM! The correct (selected) answer talks about `scripting stuff, writing apps and writing monster enterprise apps`. But as far as I think, before Scala came, we did have monster enterprise apps. :)

Comment: @c0da Yes, we did have monster enterprise apps and we did have "scripting stuff", but we usually didn't have them in the same language. The point of the answer is that Scala is both suitable to do "scripting stuff" and to do "enterprise stuff", while Java is only suitable for the latter.

Comment: I agree. But it isn't scala only which is good for scripting and monster apps. It isn't scala only which is evolving as technology advances and requirements increase. E.g. Python/Django and Ruby/Rails are good examples of cases where monster apps are there, and scripting is done in the same language too. Also regarding Java and Scala, in the end, the scala stuff comes down to Java. :)

Comment: @c0da, no, it doesn't come down to Java, it comes down to bytecode over the JVM. And similarly, for your above comment, it is not Java but the JVM which is flexible enough to allow more dynamic(ally behaving) languages like Clojure and Scala to be built on top of it.

Comment: Okies... That cleared something... :)

Comment: And, which is even more important, is Java javable.?

Answer (score 3):

Scala is very concise. The language allows you to write small scripts and simple programs with very few lines of code. Scala is excellent for small programs and removes much of the boilerplate you'd have to add in Java. For example Scala scripts don't even have to declare a Main class as entry point.

For medium sized projects Scala has very comfortable syntax that makes declarations short and precise. First class functions, closures and the likes help you to concentrate on the logic itself, not how to map it to language concepts

Scala excels at large projects. The beautiful mix of object-oriented and functional programming helps you to follow almost any programming pattern. Implicit conversions, traits, actors, ....